# Recurrence with a power of log, finding big O

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics, recurrence-relations

Facing the problem:

$$f(n) = 4f(n-1) + ({\log_{2}{n}})^{2}$$

How can I find the best approximation of $f(n)$ in the big $O$ notation?

My approach (let's assume $T(0) = 0$)

$$f(n) = 4f(n-1) + ({\log_{2}{n}})^{2} = 4^{n}*f(0) + c * \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 4^{i}*{\log_{2}^2 (n-i)}$$

What can I conclude from this sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting

$$f(n) = 4^n\cdot f(0) + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{4^i\cdot (\log_2(n-i))^2}$$

is most of the work. Just rewrite the sum as

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}{4^{n-i}(\log_2{i})^2} < 4^n\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(\log_2{i})^2}{4^i}} = C\cdot 4^n$$

to conclude that $f(n) = O(4^n)$.

---

If you want an asymptotic formula for $f(n)$, just do the same without the inequality:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}{4^{n-i}(\log_2{i})^2} = 4^n\left(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(\log_2{i})^2}{4^i}} - \sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty}{\frac{(\log_2{i})^2}{4^i}}\right)$$

$$= 4^n\left(C + O\left(\frac{\log^2{n}}{4^n}\right)\right) = C\cdot 4^n + O(\log^2{n}).$$

This gives the formula

$$f(n) = \left(f(0)+C\right)4^n + O\left(\log^2{n}\right)$$

Comment: Is it true to say that this is the best approximation (as we use inequality)? Can the  approximation be improved? Is it challenging?

Comment: Yes it is the best approximation. You know that $f(n)$ has a big-O of at least $4^n$ due to the $f(0)$ term meaning $O(4^n)$ can't be improved on